# Как отобразить градиент с изображением на всю страницу?

Tags: css3, html5

Привязка к размерам, если поставить 100% по длине и высоте, не работает. Подскажите, как реализовать изображение с градиентом на всю страницу.

Так работает:
http://jsfiddle.net/gue5a3v6/

А необходимо так: 
http://jsfiddle.net/56h28jek/ , но, увы, так не работает.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div{
position: absolute;
top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    ...
    }
```